# SAP logical database includes macro implicitly. How?

Tags: abap

We are writing a tool in Java that parses and transforms ABAP code. We therefore have no intention to write new ABAP code but our tool has to handle all of ABAP, even obsolete statements. Furthermore, I'm not an ABAP expert.

One object we see uses a macro `begin_of_block` that is defined in object `RFDBRMAC`.  That include is loaded in case the logical database `BRF` is used; using another logical database as well as no logical database at all will not load it.  But neither its corresponding object `SAPDBBRF` nor its includes mention `RFDBRMAC`.  In particular, none of the former include the latter.

How does assigning the logical database `BRF` to a program makes it include `RFDBRMAC`?

Demo program using logical database BRF. The macro is known
[image: Demo program using logical database BRF. The macro is known]

Demo program using a different logical database. The macro is unknown
[image: Demo program using a different logical database. The macro is unknown]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In transaction `SE36` display the logical DB `BRF`. Then click the pushbutton 'Selections' (or Menu: Goto / Selections or Shift + F1). This will display the include `DBBRFSEL`, where the selection screen is defined for the logical DB. On the bottom of this include you'll find what you are looking for.

To generalize this for all logical DBs, the selection screen is named `DBxxxSEL` where `xxx` is the name of the logical database, and is automatically included in all programs which use this logical database.

Comment: I edited your answer about how to generalize the solution for all programs, I see no reason why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Jozsef's perfect answer I can add that you can utilize table `D010INC` which holds all include relations between programs and includes.

[image]

Thus it's very easy to find such includes programmatically.

Comment: Well, table D010INC does not help us much because we need to know the exact mechanism/path which which one object includes another.  This table only states that the fact that it is included

Comment: The exact path is showed in this table, or you probably just misuse word *path*. For your tool this tabular way of include formalization is more useful than digging through SE36/SLDB which you even weren't aware of until now.